# Write function exponential in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the derivative of this function
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTiI7.png)

This is how i write it in the code but it gave me this

745*(1-e(-x/10)-49*x
[Derivate with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0la.png)
so I guess I wrote it wrong, since I manually did it and it gave me another result.

Could someone tell me how to express it correctly in python?

This is my code

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
from sympy import Derivative, diff, simplify, Symbol
from sympy import exp as e
printing.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")

"Calculo de la primera derivada de f"

x = Symbol ('x')
Derivative(745*(1-e(-x/10)-49*x),x, 1).doit()
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the way you have added brackets. Change the Derivative calculation like below and try `Derivative(745*(1-e(-x/10))-49*x,x, 1).doit()`

Answer (score 0):

Like [Ritwik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8029019/ritwik-g) said, you have added the brackets incorrectly, and that is why you are getting an incorrect answer.
`Derivative((745*(1-e(-x/10))-49*x),x, 1).doit()` is the right way.

And the right answer is -49 + 149*exp(-x/10)/2 according to [this](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/).

Comment: You should at least attribute to the comment you're blatantly copying from.

Comment: Sorry! I am new to this platform. I Will make sure this doesn't happen again!